# How to add url prefix after host in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I have this location:

```
location /foo {
    proxy_pass http://backend/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

When I get static from http://frontserver/foo, my requests of backed url prefix: `http://frontserver/...`, but I'd like to see `http://frontserver/foo/...`.

If I make something like `proxy_set_header Host $host/foo;` I get 400 error.
How can I make it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You should not add the URI in the `proxy_set_header` but in your `proxy_pass` directive instead. It accepts a full URI

```
location /foo {
    proxy_pass http://backend/foo; # will work
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

[proxy_pass nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass)

> Sets the protocol and address of a proxied server and an optional URI to which a location should be mapped. As a protocol, “http” or “https” can be specified. The address can be specified as a domain name or IP address, and an optional port:

Adding it to proxy_set_header would ultimately make your reverse proxy send a hostname that includes a uri, which isn't a valid hostname.

Comment: No, I get correct `html` from `http://backend/`. But my backend makes request like `/js/jquery.min.js` and so on. And my location doesn't catch it because of they doesn't have `/foo/` prefix.

Comment: `location ~ / { proxy_.. }` should be sufficient then, or do you have specific reverse proxies for specific paths in your html? Consider clarifying your question if this is not the case

Comment: This is not specifix paths in my html. I just want to add /foo/ prefix for all urls in html by nginx. Doesn't it possible?